# Dataframe Wrangling with Dates and Periods in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

There are a number of things I would typically do in SQL and excel that I'm trying to do with Pandas.  There are a few different wrangling problems here, combined into one question because they all have the same goal.

I have a data frame df in python with three columns:

```
   |  EventID  |  PictureID  |  Date
0  |  1        |  A          |  2010-01-01
1  |  2        |  A          |  2010-02-01
2  |  3        |  A          |  2010-02-15
3  |  4        |  B          |  2010-01-01
4  |  5        |  C          |  2010-02-01
5  |  6        |  C          |  2010-02-15
```

EventIDs are unique.  PictureIDs are not unique, although PictureID + Date are distinct.

I. First I would like to add a new column:

```
df['period'] = the month and year that the event falls into beginning 2010-01.
```

II. Second, I would like to 'melt' the data into some new dataframe that counts the number of events for a given PictureID in a given period.  I'll use examples with just two periods.

```
   |  PictureID  |  Period  | Count
0  |  A          |  2010-01 | 1
1  |  A          |  2010-02 | 2
2  |  B          |  2010-01 | 1
3  |  C          |  2010-02 | 2
```

So that I can then stack (?) this new data frame into something that provides period counts for all unique PictureIDs:

```
   |  PictureID  |  2010-01 | 2010-02
0  |  A          |  1       | 2
1  |  B          |  1       | 0
2  |  C          |  0       | 2
```

My sense is that pandas is built do to this sort of thing easily, is that correct?

[Edit: Removed a confused third part.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first two parts you can do:

```
>>> df['Period'] = df['Date'].map(lambda d: d.strftime('%Y-%m'))
>>> df
   EventID PictureID                Date   Period
0        1         A 2010-01-01 00:00:00  2010-01
1        2         A 2010-02-01 00:00:00  2010-02
2        3         A 2010-02-15 00:00:00  2010-02
3        4         B 2010-01-01 00:00:00  2010-01
4        5         C 2010-02-01 00:00:00  2010-02
5        6         C 2010-02-15 00:00:00  2010-02
>>> grouped = df[['Period', 'PictureID']].groupby('Period')
>>> grouped['PictureID'].value_counts().unstack(0).fillna(0)
Period  2010-01  2010-02
A             1        2
B             1        0
C             0        2
```

For the third part, either I haven't understood the question well, or you haven't posted the correct numbers in the example. since the count for the `A` in the 3rd row should be 2? and for the `C` in the 6th row should be 1. If the period is six months...

Either way you should do something like this:

```
>>> ts = df.set_index('Date')
>>> ts.resample('6M', ...)
```

Update: This is a pretty ugly way to do it, I think I saw a better way to do it, but I can't find the SO question. But, this will also get the job done...

```
def for_half_year(row, data):
    date = row['Date']
    pid = row['PictureID']
    # Do this 6 month checking better
    if '__start' not in data or (date - data['__start']).days > 6*30:
        # Reset values
        for key in data:
            data[key] = 0
        data['__start'] = date
    data[pid] = data.get(pid, -1) + 1
    return data[pid]

df['PastSix'] = df.apply(for_half_year, args=({},), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  The count for A in the third row should be 2!  But I thought that was harder to do, and that it might be easier to just count periods.  I.e. because rows 2 and 3 are both for Picture A in 2010-02, then adding the sum of the previous 6 periods would just count 1.  But if there's a way to capture that row 3 should be 2 that would be extraordinarily helpful.  Will try what you put down.

Comment: Understanding the third part of this question better, it's more involved, and will move to its own place.

Comment: @user1893148 I added a simple solution for the third part of the question. I think there is a better way to do it, but I cannot find the SO question where I saw it.

Comment: Lesson learned for messing with question structure.  This is perfect.  Thanks very kindly.  It might make sense to put this on the new question.  I don't know the right stackoverflow etiquette.

Comment: On inspection, the function above doesn't seem to count only
 the previous six months---it also counts events much farther in the past.

Comment: @user1893148 Yes, as I noted in the answer the condition `(date - data['__start']).days > 6*30` should be refined.